# Regex match numbers with spaces but not without spaces

Tags: java, android, regex

Trying to match a string of numbers with spaces in between while ignoring other strings of numbers without spaces in between them. I'd like to match 16 characters.

eg. Would like to match 12345 67890 1234 but NOT 1234567890123456

I have tried this:

```
[0-9 ]{16}
```

But this matches both sets of strings.

Comment: Does it matter how many spaces exist or does it just need to have at least one space? Are you parsing them from a string or is the entire string the combination of digits and spaces? Does  [`^(?=[\d ]{16}$)\d+ [\d ]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/iSzx05/1) work for you?

Comment: Try [`\b(?![0-9]{16})[0-9 ]{16}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/QMqsy5/1).

Comment: I'd review the answers to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46695215/regular-expression-to-match-spaces-between-numbers-and-operators-but-no-spaces-b) to understand why these suggestions are being made.

Comment: We definitely need clarification for your question. What does `16 characters` mean? Do you mean that you don't want to match if there are 16 characters (digits and spaces inclusive) in a row? So if the string was `12345 67890 12351` do you want a match of `12345 67890 1235` or no match?

Comment: @ctwheels answer works, and so does Wiktor Stribizew's answer. Thanks a lot for the quick answers that actually work.

Comment: @ctwheels it doesn't matter how many spaces are in the string. Also, 16 characters including spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used and corrected **@Wiktor Stribiżew** regex, because original regex will match a space at the beginning and the end of the number.

**Regex**: `\b(?![0-9]{16})\d[0-9 ]{14}\d\b`

**Details**:

- `\b` assert position at a word boundary `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`
- `(?!)` Negative Lookahead
- `[]` Match a single character present in the list `0-9`
- `{n}` Matches exactly `n` times
- `\d` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)

[RegEx demo](https://regex101.com/r/EAhMT1/3)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to enforcees at least one space in between numbers:

```
\d+(?:\h+\d+)+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2XMdif/1)

- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `(?:\h+\d+)+`: Match 1+ group of 1+ whitespace and 1+ digits

Comment: This would work, but doesn't limit the number of characters. But thanks.